# Creating a database by gathering data with a customized web form

Tags: database, survey

I'm going to be creating a database using data that I gather from business owners. To do this, I need a service that will allow me to create a customized form that the business owner can fill out and submit. This form will require some logic, e.g., if the owner picks option A, a text box should appear prompting for more info but the textbox would not appear for option B. It would be great if the business owner could go back and edit fields after submission. As a first step, I looked at SurveyMonkey but a) it doesn't have the ability to customize the flow of the questions in the way I desire and b) it obviously doesn't meet my need to allow the page to be editable. Does anyone have any suggestions for me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you need is a simple web page with database. 
You could use some free web host which provides you with database, free domain and some disc space. There are plenty of those.

If you dont know how to make a web page yourself, then its easy to find someone who can.

Comment: Are there any that you have used and could recommend?

Comment: You can just google "free web hosting" and the first ones are probably the best, but personally, ive used this one, and have had no problems yet.
(ps, as with most free things, you probably have to put up with some adds on the page)
[link](http://members.000webhost.com/login.php)